# Domain Authentication Error

Tags: fedora, freeipa

I have installed and configured the ipa-server and in my machine I'm running fedora workstation 30. After installing the ipa-client on my machine and well configure it I can not authenticate myself with the credentials that I have on the domain server. as you can see in the attached images, when allocating the machine in the domain gave an error like:
'failed to update dns records
missing a reverse record(s) for address(es)
could not update dns sshfp records' (please consult the attachments for better understandig)

I've removed the machine and re-allocated it in the domain and the problem persists, tried other machines that gave the same error but after upgrading three times I was able to authenticate. but in this my machine in question the authentication problem persists. but only in the password, because the user name it recognizes immediately.
-solutions already applied:

1-constant updating of the system;
2-reinstallation and reconfiguration of the machine;
3-reboot the computer countless times.

I hope someone here can help me, first to better understand this type of error, which causes and also to solve the same urgently, I have to deliver some work soon.[image]

[image]

Comment: It seems that the server hostname (/etc/hostname) can not be resolved by DNS (or the server hosts file). Is there an entry for 10.10.20.198 at your DNS server?